# Why is & used before a variable?

Tags: c

Why is `&` used here before `decks` (`scanf("%i", &decks)`)?

And if my input is any letter like 'k' then it shows an output like "1929597720". Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int decks;

    puts("enter a number of decks:");
    scanf("%i", &decks);

    if (decks<1) {puts("Please enter a valid deck number");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("there are %i cards\n", (decks*52));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&` before a variable name means "use the address of this variable".  Basically, you're passing a *pointer* to `decks` to `scanf()`

As for what happens when you enter "k" (or other invalid input) - `scanf()` is failing, and you're seeing whatever random data was already in `decks` (which was never initialized).

To avoid this, check the return value of `scanf()`, and initialize `decks`.

```
int decks = 0, scanned;

puts("enter a number of decks:");
int scanned = scanf("%i", &decks);

if ((scanned < 1) || (decks < 1)) {
  puts("Please enter a valid deck number");
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When passing stuff to scanf(), you need to pass in a *pointer* to the variable, not the variable itself. The & means "Don't take the variable, take the place in memory where this variable is stored." It's a little complicated, but it's necessary so that C can change the value of the variable.
Also, change your format string to

```
scanf("%d", &decks);
```

The garbage is because you don't initialize decks. If you put in `int decks = 0`, you would always get 0.

Comment: Well no, `%i` is fine; it can be used to read in stuff like `0xabcd`

Answer (score 1):

As every good C tutorial will teach you, the `&` sign is for getting a variable's address.

In the case of `scanf()`, this is necessary in order to tell `scanf()` where to put the requested data.

---

If you input a letter like `k`, or any non-number, `scanf()` will be disturbed by that, and if you would check `scanf()`'s return value, it would tell you that 0 items are read instead of 1.

In that case, the content of the given variable is unchanged and contains random garbage. And this is as well what you output.

Comment: I am reading head to c ebook. can you refer me some good book more for basic things.. I am very cofused about "getting an address's variable"

Comment: I think he actually meant "getting a variable's address"

Comment: _As every good book will teach you as well, the & sign is for getting a variable's address._  Never saw that in ***Hunt for Red October***.  (couldn't resist)

Comment: @Sahriarrahmansupto Ouch. Of course. Thanks to all for pointing it out and editing.

Comment: @ryyker You are right. BTW, the local telephone book doesn't contain this as well. I'll have to change that claim...