# why doesn't the second while loop run?

Tags: c

I have the following code, but why doesn't the second while loop run? Any changes to make it run?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a,b,c,d,e,f;
    while(scanf("%d,%d,%d",&a,&b,&c)==3){
        printf("ok\n");
    }
    while(scanf("%d,%d,%d",&d,&e,&f)==3){
        printf("OK\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My input is

```
1,2,3
1,5,7,4,8,7
7,8,9,...
```

Comment: Please specify what input are you providing

Comment: 1,2,3(press enter) 1,5,7, stops at this point but needs to take the input 4,8,7 (press enter) 7,8,9,..

Comment: the second loop won't run until the first one is running. try to enter less numbers and see that the first loop will stop and the second will run.

Comment: when it enter a,b,c it keeps running but when I enter a,b,c, it will stop and second while should run but it's not running

Comment: @user3121023 how to get over that issue?

Comment: @hrithikmahesh Please initialize the variables before using them (e.g `int a = 0; int b = 0;` (...)

Comment: Re "*when I enter a,b,c, it will stop and second while should run but it's not running*", That's because you have `,4,8,7` but your pattern expects `4,8,7`

Comment: @William Martens, They are initializing them with `scanf`

Comment: @ikegami is there any way to remove "," from the input stream before entering to second while loop?

Comment: @ikegami Well, it is good practice to initialize variables, or else it will result in undefined  behavior.    Check here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786921/why-we-must-initialize-a-variable-before-using-it Even if they are, always do initialize them to zero. (int his case int)   (Read your below comment. I can just provide advice.. please at least check the last link)

Comment: @Willam Martens. Again, They are already being initialized. There's absolutely no point in doing `int a = 0; a = 4;` as you suggest.

Comment: @ikegami https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747029/why-is-used-before-a-variable There **is** a point of doing so. Please read the link. (Specifically, at the accepted answer, at the "k" part)

Comment: @William Martens, No there isn't, but there is a bug that needs to be fixed. Did you not read the answer to the very question you linked? The problem is that the value retuned by `scanf` was ignored. This isn't a problem for the OP. They made sure they were initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you input "1,5,7,4,8,7<ENTER>" for the `scanf()` in the 1st `while`.

The `scanf("%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c);` reads 1 into `a`, 5 into `b`, 7 into `c` and returns `3` keeping `",4,8,7<ENTER>"` in the input buffer.

In the 2nd time through the loop, scanf finds the comma and returns `0` which terminates the `while`.

Immediately after that, in the 2nd `while`, the 2nd `scanf()` attempts to convert `",4,8,7<ENTER>"` to an integer and fails promptly returning `0` and terminating the `while`.